# Context.Provider rerendering to initial state when routing between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

AppContextProvider wraps all components, private and not.  Upon logging in, dispatch is called and the user info is updated and viewable in a private appbar.  However, when navigating to another private route, the appbar goes back to the context default state.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContextProvider>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <BarSelector isTop={true} className={styles.appBar} />
          <Router />
          <BarSelector isTop={false} className={styles.appBar} />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </AppContextProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Setting up the context provider.  This is called when navigating through the router and is resetting the value/state, even though dispatch is not being called.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import UserReducer from '../reducers/user';

let initialState = {
  User: {
    FName: 'myfname',
    LName: 'mylname',
  }
}

let AppContext = createContext();

function AppContextProvider(props) {
  console.log(`AppContextProvider !!!!!`);
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, initialState);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

Comment: It sounds like that navigation is causing the page to reload. Please share a CodeSandbox or similar that reproduces the problem.

Comment: At a minimum show the code that displays the link that you are clicking on (or whatever manner you are triggering the navigation) that causes the issue to surface.

Comment: Hey @ryan-cogswell, you got me thinking along the right path!  First, the BarSelector needed to be inside the Router.  I wrapped those and the <Switch> inside a <div>.  Then, from Material-UI inside the AppBar component, `import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'` then this, `<MenuItem component={RouterLink} to="/action">
              Action
            </MenuItem>`

Answer (score 1):

Try making the muiThemeProvider the first provider.  So the AppContextProvider is a child of the theme provider.  .

Answer (score 0):

I think using the router Re-renders the entire App component as It's inside the
BrowserRouter and thus a new useReducer function is called every Re-render and resets back to initial state, but I think you can mutate the initial state object in the reducer function,
thus even if the the component re-renders, the state will be saved in the memory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).